# Unit testing async functions in Ember controllers

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, ember.js, qunit

I've hit a very weird problem: I'm trying to make unit tests to achieve 100% testing coverage on my application. 
And of course I wrote some tests for my controllers but it seems like there is no way to test anything async in Ember (2.4.0) using ember-cli.

1. I have a function in controller that does this:

   ```
   readObject() {
      this.store.findRecord('myModel',1).then(function(obj) {
         this.set('property1',obj.get('property2');
      }.bind(this));
   }
   ```
2. I'm writing a test that should cover this function.

   ```
   test('action readObject', function (assert) {
      const cont = this.subject();
      cont.readObject();
      assert.equal(cont.get('property1'), 'someValue);
   });
   ```
3. Obivously, this assert wouldn't work because readObject() is async call but this isn't the root of the problem.   The problem is that then a callback in this.store.findRecord is being executed - my controller **is already destroyed**!  So I get "calling set on destroyed object" error there.

In other words - even if I wrap my function in a promise and reformat both functions like this:

```
readObject() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
       this.store.findRecord('myModel',1).then(function(obj) {
          this.set('property1',obj.get('property2');
          resolve();
       }.bind(this));
   }.bind(this));
}
```

and

```
test('action readObject', function (assert) {
  const cont = this.subject();
  cont.readObject().then(function() {
      assert.equal(cont.get('property1'), 'someValue);
  });
});
```

It wouldn't work, because after executing readObject() my controllers become immediately destroyed, not waiting for any callbacks. 
So, it could be any async call instead of store.findRecord - it could be Ember.run.later, for example.

Does anybody had the same issue? I've read a lot of articles  I can't believe that Ember with such a big community doesn't provide a way to make async unit tests.

If anyone has any clues - please give me a hint, cause I'm kinda lost here. At the moment I have two thoughts:

1. I'm making controllers wrong, Ember doesn't suppose any async operations inside of it.  But even if I move async calls to services - I hit the same problem with writing unit tests for them.
2. I have to decompose my functions to

   ```
   readObject() {
     this.store.findRecord('myModel',1).then(this.actualReadObject.bind(this));
   }

   actualReadObject(obj) {
      this.set('property1',obj.get('property2');
   }
   ```

to have at least callbacks body covered with tests, but this means I never get 100% testing coverage in my app.

Thank you in advance for any clues. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and looking at the [QUnit API - async](https://api.qunitjs.com/async/) I solved it. Try out following:

```
// ... in your controller ...
readObject() {
   return this.store.findRecord('myModel',1).then(function(obj) {
      this.set('property1', obj.get('property2');
   }.bind(this));
}

// ... in your tests, either with assert.async: ...
const done = assert.async(); // asynchronous test due to promises usage
Ember.run(function(){
    subject.readObject().then(function(){
      // once you reach this point you are sure your promise has been resolved
      done();
   });
});


// or without assert.async
let promise;
Ember.run(function(){
    promise = subject.readObject();
});
return promise;
```

In a case of unit tests I do also mock other dependencies, for example: store.

```
this.subject({
   property1: null, 
   store: {
      findRecord(modelName, id){
         assert.equal(modelName, "myModel1");
         assert.equal(id, 1);
         return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
            resolve(Ember.Object.create({ property2: "a simple or complex mock" }));
        })
      }
   }
});
```

I am not sure about the second case (the one without `assert.async`). I think it would work too, because the test suite returns a promise. This gets recorgnized by QUnit that waits for the promise.

Comment: Thanks for an advice, but this isn't a QUnit problem, this is an Ember one. :(

Comment: By the time when findRecord is executing its callback - controller itself is already destroyed.   As far as I understand - Ember is just executing the test inside one Ember.run call.    If anything is executed outside this call - the application is already destroyed. :(

Comment: PS:  I tried that approach with assert.async, but it didn't help too - findRecord call just started to fail with error: "Cannot read property '_internalModel' of null" while qunit was working as expected.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer. Could you check once again? "Cannot read property '_internalModel' of null" problem should be gone by now, instead of using a simple object I am creating one with ´Ember.Object.create()´. I have also wrapped both versions of the test with ´Ember.run()´. Could you confirm it yet fails?

Comment: OMG, this is a brilliant solution!  I didn't get your idea from the first time about mocking up async functions before running the test itself. :)  Thank you so much Pavol - this is exactly a kind of solution I was looking for!  And it works. :)

Comment: You´re welcome :) I am curious if there is any better solution to this. I made it out and put together myself, I am not sure if there is any better way of doing it.

Comment: Well, I didn't exactly did as you proposed, but I just mocked my async calls  into a sync ones. :)  
`test('async', function (assert) {  
  
   const cont = this.subject();  
   const myModel = cont.get('store').createRecord('myModel'); // 

   // Make store.findRecord sync
   cont.set('store',{
       findRecord(){
         return { then : function(callback) { callback(myModel); } }
       }
   });

   // Sync tests
   assert.equal(cont.get('property2'), undefined);
   cont.readObject(); // This line calls store.findRecord underneath
   assert.equal(cont.get('property2'), true);
  
 });`

Comment: yes, this would do the work, too :) My solution needs no real `store` be present to call `createRecord()` upon it, which makes it even more independent (as unit tests are recommended to be). However, as long as it's guaranteed the `store` is there in full power, why not to use `createRecord()` and override `findRecord()`. Seems fine to me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I copy my own solution here, cause code formatting in comments isn't too good.

```
test('async', function (assert) {

   const cont = this.subject();
   const myModel = cont.get('store').createRecord('myModel'); // 

   // Make store.findRecord sync
   cont.set('store',{
       findRecord(){
         return { then : function(callback) { callback(myModel); } }
       }
   });

   // Sync tests
   assert.equal(cont.get('property2'), undefined);
   cont.readObject(); // This line calls store.findRecord underneath
   assert.equal(cont.get('property2'), true);
});
```

So, I just turned store.findRecord into a sync function and it runs perfect.  And again - many thanks to Pavol for a clue. :)